# Watch webpack.config.js and re-run webpack command in response to a file change

Tags: webpack

I am using `webpack.config.js` and

```
webpack --watch --progress --debug
```

to build modules.

I would like `webpack --watch` to restart after I change `webpack.config.js` file.

Is there a webpack flag I can use?

Comment: Would be great to have a viable solution without falling back to build tools for that.

Comment: FYI, there is a open issue in the webpack git repo adressing this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/15

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have ended up using [nodemon](/questions/tagged/nodemon). `nodemon` allows [executing non-node scripts](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#running-non-node-scripts) in response to changes in a file system.

You cannot use it with `webpack --watch` because `--watch` is not going to exit. However, you can simply use it with `webpack`, e.g.

```
nodemon \
    --watch ./\
    --delay 250ms\
    --exec 'node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack'
```

`nodemon` supports [configuration files](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files) that can be used to reduce the boilerplate, ignore specific files and/or directories and produce re-usable configuration.

In addition, using `nodemon` instead of `webpack --watch` works around a known `webpack` issue, ["Does not detect minor changes to the file (added/removed whitespace, semicolon)"](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/16).

Comment: Be sure to add `--ignore {build path}` to that. Otherwise, having nodemon watching your root directory will result in a loop as your build files will trigger a change.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer my development setup to mimic my production setup as much as possible. That's why I prefer [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to nodemon, forever, etc.

Since you can roll this tool out in production and you have production ready toolsets built around it. Here's [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/) on how to get it to watch and restart.

To get this working with webpack-dev-server you would have to wrap your config in a [node server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html).

Comment: It's kinda an overkill for a simple solution of this question, but I really liked it. Looks like a much better approach on the long run!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, nope. You can, however, try a wrapper such as [webpack-build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-build). That particular feature is on their list. Perhaps that does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json, with the help of [Gajus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33109171/1577947), I landed on this:

```
{
  "name": ...
  "version": ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "rebuild": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js",
    "nodemon": "nodemon --watch webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --delay 500ms --exec npm run rebuild"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Usage: `npm run nodemon`. When a change happens in `webpack.config.dev.js`, rebuild occurs. I realize, not that original of an already great answer provided by Gajus, but offers a slight twist.

Answer (score -1):

That's easy enough. Just have any file that webpack is packing up require your `webpack.config.js` file. Then any changes to that file get registered in webpack watch.

Comment: Not really that easy. Webpack may detect the changes but won't restart itself to put the config into effect.

Comment: This will not work. It will not re-run WebPack, so this is not an applicable answer for this question intention.