# webpack + gulp + nodemon - configuration fro watch task

Tags: angularjs, gulp, webpack, nodemon

I'm stuck in a trouble with my project. I am using gulp + webpack to compile the client side. During the developing stage, I want to use nodemon to watch the file changing in the server directory and I want to find a suitable mode to watch the client side part of the project and re-run the webpack task.
Here is my gulpfile

```
gulp.task('clean:tmp', (cb) => {
    del([paths.tmp]).then(paths => {
        plugins.util.log('[clean]', paths);
        cb();
        });
    });    

gulp.task('serve', ['clean:tmp'], () => {
        const config = require('./webpack.dev.config');
        config.entry.app = paths.entry;
        return gulp.src(paths.entry)
            .pipe(webpack(config))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));

    });

    gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], () => {
        return nodemon({
            script: `${rootServer}/`,
            watch: ['server/*'],

        });

});
```

The problem is that if I run the gulp watch with webpack.config.watch = true, webpack breaks the gulp pipe logic.

I also check out this answer [Watch webpack.config.js and re-run webpack command in response to a file change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472096/watch-webpack-config-js-and-re-run-webpack-command-in-response-to-a-file-change/33109171#33109171) 
but I cannot apply the solution. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Why can't you apply the solution from your linked question?

Comment: I simply don't know how to run the nodemon script inside my gulp file... I mean, how can I run nodemon \
    --watch ./\
    --delay 250ms\
    --exec 'node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack'
inside gulp?