# hotreload with webpack.DefinePlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-hot-middleware

I have

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({consts: require(`./development.json`)})
]
```

in my `webpack.config.js`. Config is read once on webpack start, if I change anything in development.json I need to halt the webpack process and run it again.

Is there any way to track file changes for webpack? I don't see anything in [sources](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/DefinePlugin.js?source=cc)

Comment: You can find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472096/watch-webpack-config-js-and-re-run-webpack-command-in-response-to-a-file-change

Comment: This doesn't differ from restarting container manually, I want my code to fire a callback that reevaluates require. The solution in the answer assumes that we restart the whole build. In my case project build like 2 minutes. I don't wanna wait every time for a few minutes when only a small part of project changes.

Comment: Why you couldn't import `./development.json` directly in your code? You can add `json-loader` to your webpack config and import `.json` files like `.js`.

Comment: Good point, I run some code against strings in development.json, I don't want those code and constants to be exposed to frontend. I also import different json files depending if I run production or development build

Comment: You should find another solution instead of using `webpack.DefinePlugin`, because you can't apply changes only for this plugin without running build for all application.